# Enable a percent-based block of CJK characters on Travel

Tags: feature-request, spam, blocklist

So, we have [a situation on Travel](http://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/59):

[image: list of questions with primarily CJK characters in title]

I assure you, none of these are legit. This has been going on for *weeks*, at something like this volume at the same time every night, consistently. The normal IP-based blocking isn't working for these people.

At one point, Stack Exchange simply blocked all CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) characters on Travel... until [someone complained](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3358/8677) about not being able to write CJK characters in legit posts.

But this spam is almost *completely* CJK characters - easily 80-90%. I can't think of, and haven't seen, a legit Travel post with that high a percentage of these characters.

So, a solution: Block posts with >x% (probably 70-80, 90 if conservative) CJK characters. I'm not sure if the platform has this functionality yet... but it should.

So, if we do have this functionality, let's use it. Otherwise, can it be developed?

Comment: It might be easier to find some (likely low) number n such that very few legitimate [travel.se] posts have more than n consecutive CJK characters and some reasonable ϵ>0, and then start blocking posts with >(1+ϵ)n consecutive CJK characters. (At least I assume that most legitimate uses of CJK characters on [travel.se] are for giving local names of landmarks/streets/etc, and such strings would generally be fairly short.)

Comment: Since the existing block is regex-based, measuring the length in relative terms isn't straightforward. A simpler but still reasonable criterion would be: 10 consecutive Han characters.

Comment: BTW that pie chart would've been a good demonstration itself.

Comment: To target this specific spam wave one could also add `[University|College]` to the regexp.

Comment: Don't fix this too quickly, please (eyes "Marshal" badge).